# What happens when you substract two rows in octave?

Tags: octave

I'm having quite some trouble understanding this piece of code :

```
img=imread(“test.jpg”); 
c=0; 
for i=img 
   for j=1:rows(i)-1 
      c+=uint64(abs(i(j)-i(j+1))); 
   endfor 
endfor 
c
```

img is a 3 dimensional array MxNx3Color, each color goes from 1 to 255
what I don't understand is this : i(j)-i(j+1)
It does image row n - imagne row n+1

but what happens when you substract 2 rows?
for example with two 3 dimension rows (I'm guessing a row is one line in the pictures so here it represent a 3 pixel wide picture) :

```
row1 : |[125, 128, 255] [055, 011, 200] [078, 200, 159]] 
row2 : |[225, 144, 111] [120, 128, 050] [123, 122, 111]]
```

what does row1 - row2 produce?
In the end, I'd like to implement this in java.

Thanks

## edit

allright, according to this link the operation is quite simple :

http://www.philender.com/courses/multivariate/notes/matoctave.html

```
A =
   2   1
   3   2
  -2   2
  
  B =
   1   1
   4   2
  -2   1

octave: D = A - B
D =
   1   0
  -1   0
   0   1
```

but there is still one thing that I do not understand, the result, which is a matric is then turned into a regular number, what kind of magic is that?
(c += row-row)

Comment: Is the code rally designed for coloured images? Seems to be for grey scale images.

Comment: forgot the link, he seems to be using it on color image : http://www.cardinalpeak.com/blog/detecting-well-focused-images/comment-page-1/#comment-406150

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a very close look to understand the code from above. The outer loop iterates over all columns, which means it iterates over the first and third dimension. The inner loop iterates over the second dimension, so basically the code is iterating over all pixels and sums up the difference to the pixel below.

A typical matlab-ish solution would be:

```
 sum(sum(sum(abs(diff(I,1,1)))))
```

For the horizontal version you could use:

```
sum(sum(sum(abs(diff(I,1,2)))))
```

Read from inside to outside, get the difference among first (second) dimension, get absolute value, summarize over all three dimensions.

You are looking for code which could be translated to java, so here is a fully iterative solution which does not use any advanced features of the for-loop:

```
c=0;
for row=1:size(I,1)-1
    for column=1:size(I,2)
        for color=1:3
            c=c+abs(I(row,column,color)-I(row+1,column,color));
        end
    end
end
```

(code written in MATLAB but should be fully compatible to octave)